# How to implement a triplet network with NetSharedArray?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In v11.3, `NetSharedArray[]` and `NetInsertSharedArray[]` give us a mechanism of sharing weights and biases across neural networks, and this is exciting because now we can train siamese networks and do deep image ranking, and other related applications.

I don't see any applications section for either of these symbols in the documentation center, but I'd like to see how one might implement a basic Triplet Network, for example [FaceNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832). The problem is that I'm not sure how to write the triplet hinge loss in Mathematica.

**References:**

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.4661.pdf
- https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/lecture/HuUtN/triplet-loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding this post becuase it is the complete answer to the original question (I accepted Sebastian's parital answer because it was very helpful).

This code implements a MWE of what I had in mind, and adds a few follow-up questions/remarks:

```
(* Define the loss from Sebastian's post above *)
l2norm = NetGraph[{ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2)^2 &], 
   SummationLayer[]}, {1 -> 2}]; alpha = 0.2;
tripletloss = NetGraph[{l2norm, l2norm, 
   ThreadingLayer[Max[#1 - #2 + alpha, 0] &]}, {{NetPort["a"], NetPort["p"]} -> 
    1 -> 3, {NetPort["a"], NetPort["n"]} -> 2 -> 3}]

(* get triplet training data e.g. (anchor, pos, neg) *)
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
tripleBatchGenerator[assn_Association] := Module[{pi, ni, a, p, n},
  Table[pi = RandomInteger[{0, 9}];
   ni = RandomChoice[Complement[Range[0, 9], {pi}]];
   pos = Position[trainingData, x_ -> pi];
   {a, p} = Extract[trainingData, RandomSample[pos, 2]][[All, 1]];
   n = Part[trainingData, 
      RandomChoice[
       Complement[Range[Length@trainingData], Flatten[pos]]]][[1]];
   <|"a" -> a, "p" -> p, "n" -> n|>, assn["BatchSize"]]
  ]

(* Question: is this a correct/good way to make the siamese portion? *)
evalnet = NetTake[NetModel["LeNet"], {1, -3}]
aevalnet = NetInsertSharedArrays[evalnet];
pevalnet = NetInsertSharedArrays[evalnet];
nevalnet = NetInsertSharedArrays[evalnet];

(* Sow pieces into a netgraph for training *)
enc = NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}];
net = NetGraph[<|
   "aevalnet" -> aevalnet,
   "pevalnet" -> pevalnet,
   "nevalnet" -> nevalnet,
   "loss" -> tripletloss|>, {
   NetPort["a"] -> "aevalnet" -> NetPort["loss", "a"], 
   NetPort["p"] -> "pevalnet" -> NetPort["loss", "p"], 
   NetPort["n"] -> "nevalnet" -> NetPort["loss", "n"],
   "loss" -> NetPort["Loss"]}, "a" -> enc, "p" -> enc, "n" -> enc]

 (* Train it! *)
 trainResult = NetTrain[net, tripleBatchGenerator, All, MaxTrainingRounds -> 500]
```

It starts training correctly:

[image]

However, here are some follow-up questions/remarks:

1. When using a generator function, specifying the `ValidationSet` doesn't seem to work (e.g. `ValidationSet->Scaled[.1]`).
2. Is there *any good way to automate a search* for the hyperparameter `alpha` (which was randomly set to .2)?
3. Are the 3 calls to `NetInsertSharedArrays` right, is using `NetMapOperator` better?

Perhaps @Sebastian can address these to help put the finishing touches on it?

Comment: @Sebastian I'm not sure how to apply NetInsertSharedArrays correctly...

Answer (score 10):

> The problem is that I'm not sure how to write the triplet hinge loss in Mathematica.

Suppose we have three images A,B,C. For each image, we have a feature vector, $\textbf{a}=f(A)$ etc. The formula for the triplet loss is then:
$$loss({\textbf{a}, \textbf{p}, \textbf{n}}) = max(\Vert\textbf{a} - \textbf{p}\Vert^{2}  - \Vert\textbf{a} - \textbf{n}\Vert^2 +\alpha, 0)$$

First, define a `NetGraph` that computes the L2-Norm $\Vert\ldots\Vert$:

```
l2norm = NetGraph[{ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2)^2 &], SummationLayer[]}, {1 -> 2}]
```

Now the triplet loss is simply (with an $\alpha=0.2$):

```
alpha = 0.2;
tripletloss = NetGraph[{l2norm, l2norm, ThreadingLayer[Max[#1 - #2 + alpha, 0]&]}, 
  {{NetPort["a"], NetPort["p"]} -> 1 -> 3, {NetPort["a"], NetPort["n"]} -> 2 -> 3}]
```

We can evaluate this loss for three feature vectors:

```
tripletloss[<|"a" -> {3, 2}, "n" -> {3, 2}, "p" -> {1.2, 2.1}|>]
Out[145]= 3.45
```

This can be used as a loss in your triplet net.

Comment: Are there any built-in image datasets that have (anchor, positive,negative) labels to test this on?

Comment: @user5601 you can always check the [Neural Net repo](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/resourcesystem/published/NeuralNetRepository/index) or its [public face](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/) to see

Comment: @b3m2a1 I did check there first, nothing there that's relevant to triplet embeddings.